# Command-create a dispenser with infinite colored wool

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to command-create a dispenser that contain **infinite** colored wool.

What I have right now is:

```
/summon FallingSand ~3 ~1 ~ {TileID:23, Time:1, TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:35, Slot:0}]}}
```

`TileId:23` is the dispenser, and in the `Items`, `id:35` is the wool, but how can I specify the dataValue I'd like to give to the wool?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using falling sand instead of using `setblock`?  Falling sand is old-school now that other options exist.  It probably won't solve your problem, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: No, no reason except that's what I've found in tutorials. Now if you have a working solution that uses `setblock` or anything else, I take it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have infinite amount of an item in a dispenser set the count for that item to -1:

```
/summon FallingSand ~3 ~1 ~ {TileID:23, Time:1, TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1}]}}
```

To have a data value for an item in the dispenser, for example coloured wool, use the `Data:` tag:

```
/summon FallingSand ~3 ~1 ~ {TileID:23, Time:1, TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1,Data:0}]}}
```

`Data:0` will make it spawn white wool.

You may also want to switch to the `/setblock` command. Here is the same with `/setblock`:

```
/setblock ~3 ~1 ~0 23 keep {Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1,Data:0}]}
```

As you can see it is much smaller. You can also use the new `minecraft:<blockname>` format:

```
/setblock ~3 ~1 ~0 minecraft:dispenser keep {Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1,Data:0}]}
```

If there is already a block there then you might want to change to `break`:

```
/setblock ~3 ~1 ~0 minecraft:dispenser break {Items:[{id:35, Slot:0, Count:-1,Data:0}]}
```

I also think that it might eventually run out, so you can fill all the slots with the item, unless you are going to have other items in there as well. This should last a long time though so you should be fine. :D

Hope I helped!